# AppCenter's responsibility

Tags: android, react-native, visual-studio-app-center, code-push, react-native-code-push

I'm trying to figure out the CI portion that provided by AppCenter. I've implemented CodePush for my app and please correct me if my understanding is wrong.

1. We build the native android app and generate a signed apk.
2. Release the generated signed apk to playstore
3. execute command to upload bundle `appcenter codepush release-react -a <owner>/<android-app> -d Production`

The above are generally the way I understand CodePush and I've tested and working fine.

Now I've noticed that we can integrate our github project branch to appcenter, and whenever there is a `git push`, AppCenter will build it automatically and we can configure to release to playstore automatically.

Now the part I don't understand is, is this `CI auto build by AppCenter` actually nothing to do with `CodePush`?

If now my situation is only having updates on JS code side, actually when I `git-push` to repo, there isn't a need to `auto-release` to playstore right?

Comment: Have you got a solution yet? Apprently I was asking the same question and I think  appcenter is still working on this feature - to conditionally enable or disable store release from within the build script.

Answer (score 0):

Correct, Build and Push are separate services in App Center. Build does the binary build of your app while CodePush simply updates the JavaScript and related code in an Apache Cordova or React Native. They're separate workflows and it seems you want to trigger them separate ways.

If you're using CodePush, you can't also use Build to auto build and deploy the native app to devices, you're duplicating work. I'm not an expert, but you probably want to manually deploy your builds whenever you make changes to the native side of the app (which should be rarely, right?) - like when there's major updates to the native framework or new plugins added to the native app